# How change source of file, while playing? - GStreamer

Tags: python, video, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I am trying to create a program, that creates a HLS stream of two images, which switch when I input into the keyboard. I have this sample code:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst, GLib
from threading import Thread

Gst.init(None)

main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
thread = Thread(target=main_loop.run)
thread.start()

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "source")
source.set_property("location", "image1.jpeg")

decoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("jpegdec", "decoder")

freeze = Gst.ElementFactory.make("imagefreeze", "freeze")

convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "convert")

encoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("x264enc", "encoder")
encoder.set_property("speed-preset", "ultrafast")
encoder.set_property("tune", "zerolatency")

muxer = Gst.ElementFactory.make("mpegtsmux", "muxer")

queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "queue")

hls = Gst.ElementFactory.make("hlssink", "hls")
hls.set_property("max-files", 0)
hls.set_property("playlist-length", 0)
hls.set_property("target-duration", 1)

pipeline.add(source, decoder, freeze, convert, encoder, muxer, queue, hls)
source.link(decoder)
decoder.link(freeze)
freeze.link(convert)
convert.link(encoder)
encoder.link(muxer)
muxer.link(queue)
queue.link(hls)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
input()
source.set_property("location", "image2.jpeg")
input()

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
main_loop.quit()
```

The problem is when I run it and then I hit enter, the `playlist.m3u8` resets, which I don't want. This is because of the state change to READY, when I remove this state change it works but I get a warning. Is there an approach that is safe and doesn't produce a warning. Is there a way to change source while play?

I did find [gst-interpipe](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/GstInterpipe), but I couldn't get it to work and have filed an appropriate [bug report](https://github.com/RidgeRun/gst-interpipe/issues/129) there.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.